# iphone Automation testing with instrument on adhoc build

Tags: iphone, ios, automation, ios-ui-automation

i have crated a java script to run smoke test for my iphone application. i am able to run this script through instruments for build which has developer profile but when i try the same thing with build with adHoc profile (Production build), it doesn't work.

Please give me some idea that whether we can run automation test cases for adhoc build app or is there any work around for it.

otherwise i have to run these test cases only on build having developer profile which will not solve my purpose.

i get the error that 
"Target failed to run: remote exception encountered:'Failed to get task for PID 143'"

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Profiling is a kind of debugging where all processes of an app are analyzed. Debugging can only be performed on developmemt builds. You ca't expect to debug a distribution IPA. If that was allowed, you could have debugged any app from app store or even Apple's apps.

> "Failed to get task for PID 143" 
>   just means that the debugging task for the app was not retrieved and hence it can't be debugged.